# how to create individual column filter in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I am using jquery datatable of and I want to add column filter for every column seperately but am not getting any result.

My code:

```
  var oTable=$("#example").dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "bFilter": false,
           "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "sPaginationType":"full_numbers"
}).columnFilter({
    "aoColumns": [
        { type: "text" }, null, null, null, null, null, null

    ]
});
```

i have 7 columns,i want to add search for first column,i dont know what am I missing

Answer (score 0):

Add input field in required place and add the following code after initiating datatable. Tested with PHP application.

```
$('#inputFieldID').keyup( function() { oTable.fnFilter($(this).val(), 0); });
```